# Determining Frequency of Music Played on Phone

Tags: frequency, audio-player

I'm a beginner programmer in `C++` trying to develop a program that requires me to know the frequencies of the music that is being played through the earphones. It has to be digital, by analyzing the music file itself.

So for example, I would know that at time `t`, frequencies **a b c d e** are played.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That is quite a difficult problem! I would consider something easier if this is your first project.

Comment: @Oliver Yep, I realised... But I don't really mind complexity - I can always learn the concepts required. The problem is don't really know if it can even be done. Using an arduino, I hope to measure the voltage output from headphone jack. Using sensitivity & impedance, I can calculate dB. This is for determining risk of hearing loss.

But dB and dB(A) [meaning A-weighted] are non-convertible. Need freq of the music to get db(A). dB(A) is the standard used for determining how much noise you can endure. Because we are less sensitive to low freqs... so it's a rather complex case.

Comment: @Oliver I'd rather build something I want to than to build a calculator or something I don't need. I'm aware it's damn tough though. So I'm trying to see if anyone has any ideas for how to do this so I can narrow the scope of my research a little.

Comment: The topic you are interested in is DSP - digital signals processing. It is a large space. That said, within the space, the problem of decomposing a signal into its constituent frequencies is well known: This is the fourier transform. Perhaps a good starting point for your research would be libraries for applying the FFT (fast fourier transform) to .wav files. A question on the DSP stack exchange might help: http://dsp.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @Oliver Thanks so much, I'll look into it!